# Is this behavior documented in Django's field validators for foreign keys?

Tags: python, django

This is an example Python 2 code:

```
from django.db import models

def my_validator(value):
    assert isinstance(value, (int, long))

class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...) # irrelevant here

class Bar(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...) # irrelevant here
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, validators=[my_validator])
```

If I create a Foo instance, then a Bar instance (assigning the foo instance), and then validate, this code passes: the FK value to validate is not a model instance but an ID (which is an integer, by default):

```
foo = Foo.objects.create(name='foo')
bar = Bar.objects.create(name='bar', foo=foo)
```

**Edit**: I forgot to include the `full_clean()` call. But yes: the troublesome code calls `full_clean()`. In fact, the first time I noticed this behavior was when trying to treat the `value` in the validator callable, as a model instance instead of a raw value, which triggered a `int value has no attribute xxx` when trying to invoke an instance method inside the validator.

```
bar.full_clean()
```

This happens in Django 1.9. Is this documented and expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - this is implicitly referred to in the documentation for [`ForeignKey.to_field`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field):

> The field on the related object that the relation is to. By default, Django uses the primary key of the related object.

Also:

> For fields like `ForeignKey` that map to model instances, defaults should be the value of the field they reference (`pk` unless `to_field` is set) instead of model instances.

That is, by default, the `value` of the `ForeignKey` is the primary key of the related object - i.e., an integer.

You can however specify a different `to_field`, in which case the `value` would take the type of that field.

In terms of what value is passed to the validators, it seems that the assumption is implicit that this is the `to_field` (what else would you validate other than the value that is going to be stored in the database? It does not make much sense to pass a model object when validating a foreign key, because the key itself is only a pointer to the object and does not say anything about what that object should be.).

But to answer your question - there doesn't appear to be any explicit documentation stating this.

Comment: I understand how the raw value is determined, but what I was asking about being documented or not, is the fact that *validator callables* receive the raw value instead of the model instance.

Comment: I accept, if you add the content in your comment, to your answer

Comment: "In terms of what value is passed to the validators, it seems that the assumption is implicit that this is the to_field (what else would you validate other than the value that is going to be stored in the database?" @solarissmoke if you take a look at the explanation of the [.to_python](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.to_python) method it leaves the impression that we should get a an object instance. More over if you define `.clean` or `.clean_field` method of a ModelForm, again you get a model instance, so its not so clear.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that @**solarissmoke** answer is relevant to the question.

IMO, [validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) is not invoked at `objects.create`, if you want to validate your model before creating it you should either use a `ModelForm`, or call it manually.

```
foo = Foo.objects.create(name='foo')

bar = Bar(name='bar', foo=foo)

try:
    bar.full_clean()
    bar.save()
except ValidationError as e:
    # Do something based on the errors contained in e.message_dict.
    # Display them to a user, or handle them programmatically.
    pass
```

#### UPDATE:

OK, so what exactly is happening is that when you call [.full_clean()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean) we get [.clean_fields()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean_fields) called.

Inside the `clean_fields` we have something like:

```
raw_value = getattr(self, f.attname)
if f.blank and raw_value in f.empty_values:
    continue
try:
    setattr(self, f.attname, f.clean(raw_value, self))
except ValidationError as e:
    errors[f.name] = e.error_list
```

Where two thing happens:

1. We get `raw_value` for the field
2. We call `field.clean`

In the `field.clean()` we have [.to_python()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.to_python), `validate()` and `.run_validators()` called in this order, its something like:

```
value = self.to_python(value)
self.validate(value)
self.run_validators(value)
return value
```

Which Django explains here: [Form and field validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation)

**BUT**, that's not the reason why you get `int/long` in your custom `validator`.

The reason is because `ForeignKey` fields [store their values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#database-representation) in an attribute with `_id` at the end, which equals to `f.attname`. So during the whole process of validating `FKs` Django works with `int/long` values, not with objects.

If you see the [ForeignKey.validate](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L922) method, you will find out that it just checks if a row with that id `exists`.

Comment: sorry! I forgot to include the full_clean call. But yes I called it.

Comment: "*Django works with int/long values, not with objects.*"... this is not quite correct. What Django stores is the value of the primary key or (`to_field` if you specify something other than `pk`) of the foreign object. This does not have to be an integer (e.g., a unique string can also be a primary key).